# App. Server gets down while running test using latest Jmeter 3.3

Tags: jmeter

My app server gets down during load test using latest 3.3 version of jmeter, however works fine in older jmeter 2.13

Any idea, I'm not figuring out since I'm using the the same script in both of the versions.

I can notice, there is huge difference in response time. 
[image]

The other thing, I notice is the Server Memory gets piled up, not gets free up eventually while running using latest 3.3 version of Jmeter.

Please throw some light on this issue.

Comment: Can you show your test plan or explain what configuration you have?maybe some are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing the exact same application with the 2 versions ?
Is it the exact same script ?

If yes, This can be explained by lot of improvements on performances done in JMeter between 2.13 and 3.3 particularly on embedded resources download.

If you’re using it then it’s the explanation:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html